# Value too long for type character varying(256). varchar(65535) don't work

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I created table with Redshift

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS news_comments.comment_analysis;
CREATE TABLE news_comments.comment_analysis(
  comment VARCHAR(65535),
  good INT,
  bad INT,
  timestamp timestamp,
  written_time timestamp,
  DiffInMinutes INT,
  total INT,
  good_rate FLOAT,
  bad_rate FLOAT,
  male INT,
  female INT,
  age_10 INT,
  age_20 INT,
  age_30 INT,
  age_40 INT,
  age_50 INT,
  age_60 INT
);
```

And I got error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o955.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 33.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 33.0 (TID 26) (spark-master-01 executor driver): java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Value too long for character type
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Value too long for character type
  code:      8001
  context:   Value too long for type character varying(256)
  query:     402528
  location:  string.cpp:218
  process:   padbmaster [pid=22583]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

Error occured in comment, when I did upload without comment I found it work. So comment is absolute cause of this.
The problem is I set comment VARCHAR(65535), but error said me that "you set comment varchar(256)"

Even I check the table

```
show table news_comments.comment_analysis;
Show Table DDL statement
CREATE TABLE news_comments.comment_analysis (
comment character varying(65535) ENCODE lzo,
good integer ENCODE az64,
bad integer ENCODE az64,
timestamp timestamp without time zone ENCODE az64,
written_time timestamp without time zone ENCODE az64,
diffinminutes integer ENCODE az64,
total integer ENCODE az64,
good_rate double precision ENCODE raw,
bad_rate double precision ENCODE raw,
male integer ENCODE az64,
female integer ENCODE az64,
age_10 integer ENCODE az64,
age_20 integer ENCODE az64,
age_30 integer ENCODE az64,
age_40 integer ENCODE az64,
age_50 integer ENCODE az64,
age_60 integer ENCODE az64
)
DISTSTYLE AUTO;
```

varchar is set with 65535

Of course there is a way to reduce the length of comment, but I want to take the full comment. I need your advices. Thank you

Comment: you can use VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: @Sebastian Pelaez It does't work when I use VARCHAR(MAX). I got the same error

Comment: The problem also has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'll edit my tag. I'm sorry.

Comment: How about NVARCHAR(MAX), may have special characters that VARCHAR wont work with.

Comment: @Brad NVARCHAR also don't work.

Comment: Hi - can you update your question to show the code (plus sample data) that you are using to insert the data that is failing?